# Check radio button depending on value of JQueryUI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, radio-button

I have a few sliders of different behaviour on a page. One of the sliders is associated with a radio button set. When a radio button is checked, the value of the slider should update. This is working. However, I can't get the reverse to work- when the slider is moved manually, the radio button of corresponding value should be checked.

[Here's a JSFiddle of the sliders.](http://jsfiddle.net/YSh5H/2/)

Here's my JS:

```
//When radio buttons are changed, update slider - this works
$('[name="[smoker]"]').change(function () {
      var value = this.value;
      $('#smoker').slider("value", value);
});

//When slider is changed, update radio buttons - this doesn't work. The alert event never fires.
$('#smoker').change(function () {
    alert(value)
     ($('[name="[smoker]"]').attr("value", value)).attr("checked",true);
});
```

Here's my mark-up:

```
 <div class="slider" id="smoker" data-begin="0" data-end="4"></div>
 <input type="radio" class="smoker_radio" name="[smoker]" value="0" id="smoker[1]">
<input type="radio" class="smoker_radio" name="[smoker]" value="1" id="smoker[2]">
<input type="radio" class="smoker_radio" name="[smoker]" value="2" id="smoker[3]">
<input type="radio" class="smoker_radio" name="[smoker]" value="3" id="smoker[4]">
<input type="radio" class="smoker_radio" name="[smoker]" value="4" id="smoker[5]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//When slider is changed, update radio buttons 
$('#smoker').on('slidechange', function () {
     $('input[name="[smoker]"][value="' + $(this).slider('value') + '"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HFYuZ/)

Answer (score 2):

you could do:

```
slide: function (event, ui) {              
   $(".smoker_radio[value='"+ui.value+"']").attr("checked", true);
   //or better use .prop()
   $(".smoker_radio[value='"+ui.value+"']").prop("checked", true);
}
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSh5H/4/)